# Problema Creando Controller Entity Framework ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

Tengo un gran problema, estoy usando Visual Studio 2019 Preview Community, y usando el Entity framework estoy tratando de crear el controlador de un proyecto, pero me muestra este error, ya traté creando desde cero el proyecto, también recompilando pero sigue sin funcionar, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

[image: Error]

Comment: buenas, bienvenido a stack overflow en español, por lo pronto te comento que ya existe la version final de visual studio 2019 que puedes bajar del sitio de microsoft.
intenta redactar mejor la pregunta, pues entre indicar que no te deja crear controller y usar entity framework es como que fueran 2 cosas separadas, si puedes dejar una captura de como esta armada lasolucion del explorador de soluciones o que menus utilizar para crear el proyecto seguramente servira.